# Grunt + Functional Testing

Tags: testing, gruntjs, automated-tests

I have grunt tasks setup to do some functional tests with CasperJS on my local machine.  Everything is working fine.

I'd like to know if there is a way to keep running the tests until it fails? Or run through the tests a certain number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell you can "cd" to the directory and use the following one-liner:

```
do { grunt } while (1 -eq 1}
```

Here is the equivalent in Bash:

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do grunt done
```

This should run grunt over and over in an infinite loop and you can stop with `ctrl + c`.  If you want it to stop as soon as it fails you will need a script (I am providing the Bash as I am not very familiar with powershell):

```
#! /bin/sh
result=0
while [ $result -eq 0 ]; do
  grunt || result=1  
done
```